# Swift Physicsbody pinned and joined not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

I'm trying to create a simple car with `SKSpriteNode`. Physics and everything works great, except for one tiny thing: when my car lands on the ground from a greater distance the body of the car is pushed down and then goes back to its place.

See image:
[image: How it looks like for a moment after it landed]

I want to get the left image, but I get the one on the right.

When it lands on the ground I don't want the body to go into the wheels, I want it to be in a fixed place relative to the wheels or vice-versa.

So here is how I do it:

This is in the car class:

```
carWheelJoint1 = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(self.physicsBody!, bodyB: leftWheel.physicsBody!, anchor: leftWheel.position)
carWheelJoint2 = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(self.physicsBody!, bodyB: rightWheel.physicsBody!, anchor: rightWheel.position)
```

And this is in the GameScene class:

```
//Add vehicle
vehicle = DevCar(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 50), cameraThreshold: cameraThreshold)
vehicle.position = (CGPoint(x: 0, y: cameraThreshold))
addChild(vehicle)

self.physicsWorld.addJoint(vehicle.carWheelJoint1)
self.physicsWorld.addJoint(vehicle.carWheelJoint2)
```

I tried using `SKPhysicsJointFixed` but that did not work either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: this is how the physicsBody is defined:**

Here is the car body in the car class.
The car class is an `SKSpriteNode` and is the body of the car itself, the wheels are its children.

```
    let baseBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
    baseBody.mass = CGFloat(1)
    baseBody.dynamic = true
    baseBody.affectedByGravity = true
    baseBody.friction = 0.2
    baseBody.allowsRotation = false
    baseBody.density = CGFloat(10)

    self.physicsBody = baseBody
```

And here is the wheel body in the same class:

```
    leftWheel = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: wheelSize)
    leftWheel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / -2 + wheelSize, y: size.height / -2 - wheelSize)

    rightWheel = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: wheelSize)
    rightWheel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2 - wheelSize, y: size.height / -2 - wheelSize)

    leftWheel.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: wheelSize)
    leftWheel.physicsBody!.mass = CGFloat(0.2)
    leftWheel.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    leftWheel.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    leftWheel.physicsBody!.friction = 0.3

    rightWheel.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: wheelSize)
    rightWheel.physicsBody!.mass = CGFloat(0.2)
    rightWheel.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    rightWheel.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    rightWheel.physicsBody!.friction = 0.3

    addChild(leftWheel)
    addChild(rightWheel)
```

**EDIT2: Added video**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTwa-t4u4pI

Comment: Did you actually create the physics bodies for each of the nodes? Your code doesn't show it. By default, nodes do not have a physics body. If you do, can you share your code for this?

Comment: @jcaron please see the edit

Comment: Just set your restitution on your physics body to 0 if you do not want a bounce effect

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I tried that but did not work. I tried to set the restitution of the car body, the wheels, even the ground to 0. It did not work :/  Please see video in edit2 for reference.

Comment: remove the mass and see if it is still bouncing.  you may have too much physics going on here that something breaks

Comment: @Knight0fDragon that's a nice advice. It reduced that bounce effect by ~90%, but it is still there. If no solution or comment is given anymore I'll submit your comment as solution.

Comment: post the updated code,  something must me missing here,  zero restitution and zero mass should not cause any bounce

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I uploaded the class to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/AR1JfLbV

Comment: I'd like a link to the project so I can play around. or at least an example of how you're actually using the class in your gamescene! -thanks